# How many Britons consider that Brexit has negatively affected them, now that COVID has been mostly contained?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, public-opinion

According to [this Financial Times movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wO2lWmgEK1Y&ab_channel=FinancialTimes), the UK has been significantly economically impacted by Brexit. According to them, this became clearer after COVID had been largely contained, but its economic consequences are still combined with those created by the Russian invasion of Ukraine:

> The UK's recent disastrous "mini" Budget can trace its origins back to
> Britain's decision to leave the European Union. The economic costs of
> Brexit were masked by the Covid-19 pandemic and the crisis in Ukraine.
> But six years after the UK voted to leave, the effect has become
> clear. In this film, senior FT writers and British businesspeople
> examine how Brexit hit the UK economy, the political conspiracy of
> silence, and why there has not yet been a convincing case for a
> 'Brexit dividend'.

However, the film seems to cherry-pick a few persons to speak about Brexit economical consequences and I am not sure if this is representative of the entire population.

[This IPSOS survey from March 2021](https://www.ipsos.com/en-uk/6-10-say-brexit-has-made-no-difference-their-daily-life) indicates that most Britons say Brexit has made no difference to their daily life (~60%), with only about ~30% mentioning that they had been negatively affected. However, this survey is rather old, since it does not take into account the post-COVID economical recovery.

Is there a more recent similar survey that shows how Britons feel about the economical consequences of Brexit?

Comment: Has the coronavirus really mostly been contained? Recorded daily deaths due to COVID-19 in the United Kingdom are roughly near the levels from the end of September of last year, and fewer people are being tested. I would suggest that all that has really been contained is people's caution.

Comment: The film seems to be making the claim that Britian has been significantly economically impacted by Brexit, not the claim that most Britons *feel* it has.  Of course the latter is a lot easier to measure, but just because most people believe something doesn't make it true.

Comment: O'Zaic is correct. The claim in the question is not the claim in the article.

Comment: @Obie2.0 so in other words deaths are close to the minimum from last year, with no non-pharmaceutical intervention, accounting for <2% of deaths, and excess deaths are averaging zero across the year… Sounds pretty contained to me.

Comment: @Tim - Well, if you think COVID-19 was contained last year, then sure? That is a legitimate perspective. I don't, though. Also, there are some mistakes in what you are saying: the minimum seven-day average for recorded daily deaths in 2021 was around 8 per day, whereas it is currently around 140 (about 23 times as high). Also, I seriously question the notion that excess deaths are averaging zero across the year: that would imply that far fewer people are dying from some other cause to balance out the deaths due to COVID-19.

Comment: I also question the notion of "no non-pharmaceutical intervention." Government data suggests that around [30% of adults are still using face masks at least occasionally.](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/healthandsocialcare/conditionsanddiseases/articles/coronaviruscovid19latestinsights/lifestyle), and 15% or so are still testing. Do also keep in mind that your <2% makes COVID-19 the [10-12th-leading cause of death in the UK](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/deaths/bulletins/monthlymortalityanalysisenglandandwales/september2022).

Comment: Back in February it was much higher, at the third-highest cause of death, ahead of any other contagious disease. Cases seem to be rising again (no surprise, since it is seasonal), so it could be back there before long.

Comment: "Normalised" might be a better word than "contained".  There was a window where it was possible to truly eliminate COVID.  The political will isn't there anymore to do so.  Peoples and governments have adjusted their lives, risk tolerance, and expectation of mortality to accept the current levels of infection.  For better or worse.

Comment: Anecdotally, Brexit hasn't (yet) affected this Briton. But I got the hell out of Dodge (aka emigrated to a country in the EU) before it could affect me. That doesn't mean I don't think it was an idiotic idea and damaging to the country.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In fact, Ipsos ran surveys with identical questions to the March 2021 one you've linked to in both June 2021 and June 2022. The full report may be found [here](https://www.ipsos.com/sites/default/files/ct/news/documents/2022-06/EU_and_UK_interests_polling_June_2022.pdf), but I've taken an excerpt of the graph showing the most relevant figures below.

[image]

Ipsos provided the following commentary on the changes in [its news post](https://www.ipsos.com/en-uk/almost-half-britons-say-brexit-has-made-their-daily-life-worse-1-3-say-it-has-made-little):

> New polling by Ipsos UK in partnership with the EU:UK Forum shows that
> the proportion of Britons who think the UK’s exit from the EU has made
> their daily life worse has risen from three in ten in June 2021 to 45%
> now. Seven in ten of those who voted Remain feel this is the case, up
> from half last year – and the proportion of Leave voters who say the
> same has doubled over the same period, from 10 to 22 per cent.
>
> At the same time, the proportion of those who say that Brexit has made
> their daily lives better has also risen, although they remain a
> smaller group: seventeen per cent say this is true, up from one in ten
> in June 2021. Among Remain voters, one in ten now say Brexit has made
> daily life better (up from 5% in 2021) – while a quarter of Leave
> voters say the same, an increase from 17% a year ago.
>
> The proportion who say it has made no difference has shrunk from half
> in 2021 to a third now.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that this is subjective data. The most interesting part is the 'Better+Remain' would be nice to see more details on that group.

Comment: @Jontia It was mostly a drastic reduction in "No difference", from 41% to 18%. Assuming the people who switched from "Better" to "Worse" (and vice versa) balanced, that means that that 23% change split by a factor of almost 4 favoring "Worse".

Comment: In interpretation of the reduction of “no difference” responses is that people are more likely to explain their circumstances with reference to Brexit now that Covid isn't the most salient feature of public life.

Comment: interesting stats, the majority still don't see Brexit as having negative effects on their life

Comment: The real takeaway from those polls seems to be that the "it had no effect" position is hemorrhaging adherents.

Comment: _"[...] the majority still don't see Brexit as having negative effects on their life"_ and (surprise!) an even larger majority don't see Brexit as having positive effects on their life...

Answer (score 10):

According to information from [Tony Blair Institute For Global Change](https://institute.global/policy/moving-how-british-public-views-brexit-and-what-it-wants-future-relationship-european-union), 59% of Britons think Brexit has worsened the UK economy, and most voters rate the effects of Brexit on their lives negatively, particularly when it comes to ease of doing business with the EU and trade. This particular paper came out in October 18th, 2022, so it came out pretty recently:

> Most Britons think Brexit is not “done”, including over a third of Leavers and almost a third of 2019 Conservative voters.
> An overwhelming majority of the public (59 per cent) think that Brexit has worsened the UK’s economy, including over a third of Leavers (34 per cent). Voters from all major political parties believe that Brexit has made the economy worse rather than better.
> Most voters view the effects of Brexit on their lives as mostly negative, particularly on trade (net -52 per cent) and ease of doing business with the EU (-45 per cent).
> The consequences of Brexit are seen most negatively in Northern Ireland, Scotland and the North East of England.                                             *- Moving On: How the British Public Views Brexit and What It Wants From the Future Relationship With the European Union*

Comment: *"59% of Britons think Brexit has worsened the UK economy"* - it's important to put that figure into context. 49% thought it would be an asteroid strike to the British economy even *before* Brexit, so the implication seems to be that the happening of Brexit has changed the opinion of just 1 in 10 people, and only 20% of those who actually voted for Brexit have changed their minds since.

Comment: @Steve Of the remaining 80% or leave voters, some won't admit, even to themselves, that brexit is the cause of things being  worse as they would mean they  were wrong.  Or they accept the arguments that it's all covid's/Putin's fault.

Comment: @ChrisH, indeed there have been confounding events like Covid and Putin, but Remainers also greatly overstated the consequences. It was said there would be "food shortages" for example, so when nobody suffered any real shortage of food, the bluff seemed to be called. Also, many people's attitudes to such warnings in the context of a mere political reconfiguration, was not that "we better stay in the EU", but "we better improve our food security and break the sheer dependency and instability of the existing arrangements".

Comment: @Steve I only recall warnings of (overall) food shortages as being caricatures of the warnings of shortages of certain imported nice-to-have items, and whether because of brexit or otherwise there have certainly been gaps on the shelves.  But more importantly, food inflation and food shortages are basically the same thing to those without enough money to afford the price rises

Comment: @ChrisH, my recollection is that nobody ever said the quiet part "certain imported, nice-to-have items", because nobody would be swayed by shortage of caviar, and the only real *gaps* have been due to panic buying. As for food inflation, the only credible means by which Brexit is said to cause this, is by forcing more reliance on workers in Britain - either as food workers, or at least as border clerks. For many, causing that kind of inflation, and forcing their labour to be better paid and more fully employed or strongly demanded, was part of the point of voting Brexit. (1/2)

Comment: That is, inflation caused (or said to be caused) by *wage increases* is not a sign that Brexit hasn't worked, but a sign that it *has*! A lot of Remainers in my experience don't seem to understand how the same happenings (like the steam whistle of inflation, and the government talking about it being caused by rising wages) are interpreted differently by Brexiteers, as a sign not of failure, but as a successful reconfiguration of economic forces which now means their wages are on the rise. Whether the inflation is caused purely by wages is another question, but you seem to think it is. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve I definitely don't think inflation is caused mainly by wage rises even in the foods that aren't imported, and didn't mean to imply so.  But you make a good point about the interpretation of what wage rises are taking place, the most relevant probably being supermarket workers.  (TBH I'm more likely to blame inflation on profiteering by multinationals given how their accounts are looking, but I suspect that's a bit far from the original topic)

Comment: @ChrisH, then how do you explain why certain imported things are more expensive? You earlier claimed that food prices had risen due to Brexit. I think like you do that current inflation is mainly driven by profits. But I see no explanation for why Brexit should have boosted those profits. Oil profits, for example, have been sent soaring because a major world producer is under heavy sanctions, just as demand has also soared to build stockpiles.

Comment: @Steve the exchange rate, for starters

Comment: @ChrisH, well that is a fair point, and the rate did jar down upon Brexit, but equally the current rate is not dissimilar to the level in the early 2010s when we were firmly in the EU and before Brexit was even a word - so any currency effect was just as great 10 years ago as it is now. Moreover, a weaker pound encourages domestic production for domestic sale and foreign exports, and discourages foreign production and foreign imports for domestic sale. Again, are you sure you're not speaking at cross purposes to those who would benefit from stronger domestic demand?

Answer (score 9):

Nothing all that different from the 2 previous answers, except that Statista seems to be tracking this as an ongoing event and will likely provide more data at [Brexit opinion poll 2022 | Statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/987347/brexit-opinion-poll/) in the future.

> As of July 2022, 52 percent of people in Great Britain thought that it was wrong to leave the European Union, compared with 36 percent who thought it was the right decision. During this time period, the share of people who regret Brexit has been slightly higher than those who support it, except for some polls in Spring 2021, which showed higher levels of support for Brexit. The share of people who don’t know whether Brexit was the right or wrong decision has generally been consistent and usually ranged between 11 and 14 percent.

The relevance of Covid mentioned in the question follows:

> The surge in support for Brexit that occurred in Spring 2021 may have been related to the United Kingdom’s fast rollout of vaccinations for COVID-19. Compared to other major European countries, the UK had managed to vaccinate a far higher share of its population by Spring 2021, although other countries did catch up in the summer. The relatively fast procurement process of the UK was contrasted with a more cautious bureaucratic EU, supporting some of the key sentiments that drove the Brexit vote. Since that point, the fall in support in support of Brexit mirrors the government’s sinking approval ratings, especially since the Prime Minister Boris Johnson is heavily associated with Brexit and the Leave vote.

This has generally been trending towards the Bad Idea camp, albeit slowly.